# Android emulator missing hardware profile

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using android emulator for testing my application developing using eclipse in various devices, I want to test my application in large screen devices like Samsung galaxy Tab Neo , For that I create a new hardware profile that matches to Samsung galaxy Tab Neo and used this hardware profile in an emulator, The emulator works fine for first time and its damaged after opening later,I found that the hardware profile I created for Samsung galaxy Tab Neo is missing, **How can I store this hardware profile permanently in my pc?**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can "Export" hardware profile(s) after creation (in menu appeared on right mouse button click on profile in list). It will be "devices.xml" file in specified folder. After disappearing profile in Studio you can press "Import Hardware Profiles" button below list and choose saved "devices.xml".

My hardware profiles disappear after each machine (Windows Server 2016) reboot.

Answer (score -1):

This might be a bug, you could try one of the following:

**(1)** Your AVD instance may work if you start it by your own

- Search for AVD Manager in your Android directory and execute it outside your ID as administrator.

**(2)** Try to clone an existing device definition

- In your AVD Manager instance from (1) you should see the tab "Device Definitions". Choose your device there and click "Clone". You now have a modifiable copy where you can adjust your settings and use it later on as your running virtual device.

**(3)** On Windows the RAM setting can cause problems

"On Windows, emulating RAM greater than 768M may fail depending on the system load. Try progressively smaller values of RAM if the emulator fails to launch."

Hope something helps.